# Android - Error: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, apk

I have changed my package name of my app. Now this error is showing when i want to build apk.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is my module build.gradle
 file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.previewtechs.blacklistpro"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile files ('libs/libphonenumber-7.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What is the problem? and what to do to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: have you change package name in  gradle ?

Comment: I just changed applicationId in module build.gradle. Where to change package name on  build.gradle?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Please check whether do u have any duplicate jars or aar's?

Comment: Can u post your gradle?

Comment: Updated my post with module level build.gradle file. @Raghavendra